# spring boot app redirection to another controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

My task is sent request from frontend to contoller x, make some logic in it, and based on that redirect to controller y or not, my questions are:

1. how to redirect  from x controller to y controller (with all request headers and query params I sent from frontend to controller x) .
2. how to lock controller y so I can't access it directly from frontend (the only access is through controller x).

Comment: Why is y a controller, if you don't actually want to expose it? Just write a *service*, and talk to it in terms of your domain logic rather than transport layer stuff like request headers and query parameters. What is the actual task; what led you to this as a solution?

Comment: ok thank you first for your answer , controller x is general and based on logic i do in it i navigate to another controller so it may be y , z , ....
i dont want to edit all these files and make all my edits in few files only .

but if i dont found a way to do that i will do what you told me xd

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're really asking, could you give a [mcve] that illustrates the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: i tought that was minimal xd, ok
i send form form frontend and need before send it to validate with google recaptca so i validate recaptcha at controller x then if success redirect to controller y

Comment: Please [edit] the question; don't just describe it, give examples. I think this is an XY problem.